# call ID from other table to display current table information

Tags: php, sql

I want to display lectures information from lectures table while the conditions are; the same id as the teacher and as the course.so, I want to get course ID but it doesn't work. the system is that the teacher chooses a specific course to see its lectures. any suggestions?

```
    <?PHP if($_GET)$getid= $_GET['id'];$q=mysqli_query($con,"select id from courses id='$getid' ");$n=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);$id=$_SESSION['user'];





             $teachid=$_SESSION['user']['id'];
            $query = "SELECT * FROM lectures WHERE teacher_id=$teachid AND course_id=$getid";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['subject']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['post']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['photo']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['teacher_id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['social_url']; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row['course_id']; ?></td>

                    <td></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" class="button" name="doEdit" value="<?PHP echo $row['id'];?>">Edit</a>
                   <button type="submit" class="button" name="doDelete" value="<?PHP echo $row['id'];?>">Delete</a></td>


              </tr>

<?PHP }
    unset($row);
    ?>
```

Here is the lectures table:

```
  `lectures`; CREATE TABLE `lectures`
 ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `post`
 text NOT NULL, 
`photo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `teacher_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `social_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
`created` datetime NOT NULL,
 `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
 `course_id` int(11) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And courses table:

```
`courses`; CREATE TABLE `courses`
 ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `photo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `course_cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `institute_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `description` text NOT NULL,
 `teacher_id` int(11) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What I want basically is to display the table of lectures based on the ID of courses and the id of the registered teacher.

Comment: What's `select id from courses id='$getid'` supposed to do? Check if that ID exists? But I don't see where `$n`is used. Care to give me a pointer on that? I strongly recommend you read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). (And some newline here an there would make it  easier to read.)

Comment: thanks but I tried many times to check if the `id` in courses table is equal to `course_id` in lectures table so the teacher can click on that specific course and all lectures that associated to that particular course can be shown based on the teacher and the course. Any other solution?

Comment: Maybe consider posting the tables structure along with some sample data. It might help to understand the problem.

Comment: Here is the `courses` table
 id Primary int(11)   
 course_cat_id int(11)   
             user_id int(11)   
 institute_id int(11)   
 description text 
 teacher_id int(11)

Comment: Please edit your question for the description of the tables. The (small) comments aren't suitable for that.

Comment: I did and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add `echo $query;`after `$query = "SELECT ...";` run your script and tell what it has printed as query?

Comment: it says `Notice: Undefined variable: getid` Also same variable in  `SELECT * FROM lectures WHERE teacher_id=256 AND course_id=` and also `Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean`

Comment: So that means your course id is empty, the query thus fails and doesn't return a result. Do you have the course id in your query string in the URL (the part after the `?`, not to be mistaken with the SQL query here!).

Comment: I didn’t get your comment. But yeah the ‘course_id’ in the lectures table is the same as the ‘id’ in the courses table. When I delete the part which is ‘get id’ and only call the teacher session with the condition in SELECT where ‘teacher_id’ =teacher session, it displays an output with all lectures that associated with that teacher but with all courses and not that selected course that the teacher chose.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you have an empty value in `$getid`. Because of that, your query will look like e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM lectures WHERE teacher_id=7 AND course_id=;
```

(Note, that there is no value right of the second `=`.)
That's an invalid query, that doesn't retrieve anything from the database, but just triggers an error.

`$getid` is set in the first line,

```
if($_GET)$getid= $_GET['id'];...
```

, to the contents of $_GET['id']. That is, it's set to the value of `id` in the query string of the request.

A query string is the part in an URL after an `?` in the end of it. Assuming your script is called `myscript.php` and is in the root of a web serer at `www.myserver.com`, the URL in the address field of your browser must look like

```
http://www.myserver.com/myscript.php?id=4
```

to have the value of *4* in `$_GET['id']`, then in `$getid` an finally in the query's second comparison. (Note the `id=4` in the end. Somewhere in the end, after the `?` this must be written somewhere. But it not necessarily needs to be the only one. E.g. `...?someotherarg=hello&id=4&yetsomeotherarg=world` is also OK.)

(Note: I assumed the funny looking first line is working correctly as you don't report PHP syntax errors. Though it's looking a little unorthodox to me. You might consider to replace it with a more "friendly" and "standard"

```
if ($_GET)
{
    $getid = $_GET['id'];
}
```

if my assumption is wrong and it isn't working properly. As already mentioned the SQL request in that line doesn't do anything useful too. It's results are never used anywhere else, as far as I could see. So I suggest you delete that as well. It's just unnecessarily confusing when reading the code.)